# How can the Toy object I get from a Child object not be the same as passed in through the constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, assert, testcase

I am doing an assignment that requires me to create the code that will make this run with no errors or failures. This is only one test case:

```
Toy t1 = new Toy(1000121, "Red Bike", 3, 98.90);
Toy t2 = new Toy(1000123, "Colouring Book", 4, 19.89);
Toy t3 = new Toy(1000128, "Skateboard", 5, 149.99);
Toy t4 = new Toy(1000127, "SpongeBob DVD", 3, 14.99);
Toy t5 = new Toy(1000130, "Bike Helmet", 1, 18.99);
Toy t6 = new Toy(1000125, "Toy car", 10, 3.99);
Toy t7 = new Toy(1000129, "Ball", 2, 5.59);
Toy t8 = new Toy(1000189, "Teddy Bear", 3, 10.79);

Toy[] listofToy1 = { t1, t2 };

Child c1 = new Child("James", 1, listofToy1);

assertTrue(c1.getChildToy().length == 2 && c1.getChildToy()[0] != t1 && c1.getChildToy()[1] != t2);
assertTrue(c1.getChildToy().length == 2 && c1.getChildToy()[0].getToyName().equals("Red Bike") && c1.getChildToy()[1].getToyName().equals("Colouring Book"));

assertTrue(c1.getChildToy().length == 2 && c1.getChildToy()[0].getToyQuantity() == 3 && c1.getChildToy()[1].getToyQuantity() == 4);
```

My question is how does the first assertTrue even work? Am I missing something?

You can infer what each method means by what its called. For reference, the `getChildToy` method will return an array of Toy objects. The toy objects are from the created Toys from line 1-8

To me it looks like `Child c1` is created with an array of toys that include `t1` and `t2` in index 0 and 1, respectively. So how can `c1.getChildToy()[0]` not equal `t1` from the first assert?

And if `c1.getChildToy()[0]` is not equal to `t1`, how can `c1.getChildToy()[0].getToyName().equals("Red Bike")` from the second assert be true?

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Edit: I tried system.out.println.

```
System.out.println(c1.getChildToy()[0].getToyInformation());
System.out.println(c1.getChildToy()[1].getToyInformation());
```

console showed this:

```
(1000121, "Red Bike", 3, 98.90)
(1000123, "Colouring Book", 4, 19.89)
```

which is a match to line 1 and 2

P.S. getToyInformation method just puts the info from the toy object into a formatted string

Comment: Suggestion: Consider editing the question's title - it should summarize the specific problem.

Comment: We can answer more easily and with more certainty if you provide a [mre], please?

Comment: If you are cloning objects, where is that code? Show us the `Child` constructor.

Comment: I am confused as to whether the code already exists or it’s code you have to write in your assignment. If you haven’t written the code yet, how can you run your `System.out-println()` calls?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to think `==` means "same content".

It doesn't. It means 'same reference'.

What the method is testing is that the `Child` constructor takes its toy input (the third argument) and **clones every toy object**.

Imagine I build a house.

I then build the exact same house next door. Same layout. Walls painted the same colour. I even decorate them identically.

Are they the same house? No. But, they are the same design.

`house1 == house2` would be false because it's not the same house.

`house1.equals(house2)` is true, though.

We can trivially see this in java:

```
String a = "Hello".toLowerCase();
System b = "Hello".toLowerCase();
System.out.println(a == b); // false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
```

We made 2 strings here. However, they so happen to have the same content. They're like the 2 identical houses.

Note that the whole setup here (arrays, mutable objects, defensive cloning) is 20 years out of date code style, I don't know what course or tutorial this is, but, oof. It's *very* out of date.